# How to make nginx try_files log file when it is not found?

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    server_name foo.com;

    listen 80;

    root '/var/www';

    location /divergent {
        try_files 'bar' =400;
    }
}
```

In this example, I would like to get a message such as:

```
2015/03/27 17:53:49 [error] 25248#0: *1 open() '/var/www/bar' failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.187.147.109, server: foo.com, request: "GET /bar HTTP/1.1", host: "foo.com"
```

I would like to get the above message; I do get it sometimes, sometimes I do not. I do not understand what makes the message to propagate.

HTTP block is configured to log all messages:

```
http {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    # ...
}
```

Comment: You know that `try` is not an argument, right?  Make sure it's `try_files`.  And if `bar` is just a file, then you need to replace `'bar'` with just the full path or relative path.  Such that it becomes `try_files bar =400;`

Comment: Sorry, `try_files` it is; typo in the example. I am intentionally trying to trigger an error. There is no such 'bar' file.

Comment: How about you change the `try_files` line to actually make a request, such that `try_files $uri =404;` and make a request to the server for something that doesn't exist?  It should then show an error.  Assuming you reload the configuration after changing it.

Comment: For the record `log_not_found` is `on`.

Comment: For the record, I did not manage to do this using the standard nginx build. I have used build with `--with-debug`.

Comment: @Gajus Please add your solution and check it as valid so people could understand what you've done ;) thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

This was achieved by rebuilding Nginx with debug information, using the `--with-debug` flag. For build instruction, see [debugging log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) documentation.

This allows printing additional information using `error_log /path/to/log debug;` instruction. See [error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) for details.